# Query list from multiple countries in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I wanted to try `NoSql` and started my project in `Firebase`. My app's data has increased a lot. However, now I need to run a country-specific app and hence show/filter data according to countries in my app.

The structure of my current data is as follows.

```
{ clients:  {
  "04E2LBixKoVn9sGzRvxtMoC7MsF3" : {
    "clientName" : "Rising Mall",
    "contact" : {
      "branches" : {
        "-Kx6QoVhr0WpDQ3i68_n" : {
          "address" : "Test Location",
          "phone" : "999999999",
          "country": "USA"
        }
      },
      "mail" : "test@test.edu.np",
      "website" : "http://www.test.np"
    },
    "description" : "Test Description."}
  },
  "073ezb0UsgetSef0lwk50dhogjM2" : {
    "clientName" : "Leather Craft",
    "contact" : {
      "branches" : {
        "-Kx6QoVj_QKM7tjekh_1" : {
          "address" : "Test Location",
          "phone" : "888888888"
          "country": "UK"
        }
      },
      "mail" : "test@test.com",
      "website" : "https://www.test.com"
    },
    "description" : "Test"
   }
}
```

From the above structure, I want to get a list of all the clients whose country is "USA". How can I do it directly by querying `FirebaseDatabase` in Android? Is it possible? Or do I have to change the structure of my database completely? If I have to restructure my database do suggest a solution to that as well.

UPDATE

I took the suggestion given by @alex-mamo and designed all my structures by denormalizing the data.

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- usClients
           |
           --- usClientId1 : true
           |
           --- usClientId2 : true
```

Comment: you should change your database structure. it was possible but takes much methods

Comment: @NikunjParadva Is there any suggestion for structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you don't need to restructure your database entirely, you just need to change it a little bit. To solve this problem, you need to add another node to your database named `usClients`. Every time you add a new user which is from USA, add it also in this new created node. Your new node should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- usClients
           |
           --- usClientId1 : true
           |
           --- usClientId2 : true
```

Whith this structure you can query your database to get only the clients within USA. This can be done attaching a listener on `usClients` node and iteration on the `DataSnapshot` object.

This practice is called denormalization and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Comment: Thanks. I'll dive into the video and see how I can structure my db.